# input type="file" to add attachment to mail?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I'm trying to make my form send an attachment to a mail adress through a mail.

I have an input type=file in my form but all it seems to do is add the name of what i want to send as an attachment in the mail.
**I'm not working with servers or php**, just html,css and javascript. I'm not even sure if input type=file is ment to do that?
Am i on the right track? Completely wrong? **Is there a way to add a file in a mail through a form or..?**

Thanks in advance people! :)

Comment: this can only be processed using a server-side language like PHP, Java or .NET...

Comment: How is it sending the email without a server currently?

Comment: @JohnBoker That's the right question. But as everyone here sais that it must be done with server-side languages i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need more than client side technology to do that, you will need a backend such as php,java,ruby etc. to handle the sending of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with this inside the mail header:

```
Content-Type: jpg; name=$file
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file
chunk_split( base64_encode( $file ) )
```

This is only an **not** working example! Make a research for a correct one. But that parameters with \n are what you need!

If you don't work with servers, now you have to do it! Make a AJAX to this PHP-script which will send the mail!